# Why do we need a transistor with a dc motor while we don't need one with a servo motor?

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, servo

I was wondering why do we need to attach a transistor as we don't need one while we connect the Arduino with the servo motors. I am using mini servos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A servo typically has 3 wires: Power, Ground, and Signal

Inside the servo are a bit of electronics that read the input signal duty cycle, the absolute position of the horn, and power the motor in forward or reverse accordingly. There are transistors inside the servo housing to handle the high current of the motor.

A standalone motor doesn't have any other control electronics that separate power from control inputs.

**EDIT:**

Just to clarify: the signal wire for the Servo doesn't carry any significant power. The IO pins on the Arduino should not be asked to provide more than 40mA of current, and the PWM signal to the servo falls under that current limit.

But to operate a motor, or other device which draws significant operating power, it (the motor) asks for much more than 40mA of current, which can burn out the IO pin and damage it forever. This is why a transistor or other "switch" is necessary: the device which switches the high-current on and off can itself be operated by a very low current.

Answer (score 0):

Because a servo contains a driver circuit that controls the motor portion, whereas a motor doesn't. The transistor is the (simplistic) driver circuit for the motor.